# AggregateResult throws error: System.ListException: Row with null Id at index: 0

Tags: apex, trigger

I have this Apex SOQL query:

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
    select accountid id, min(id), min(Partner_Admin_Sequence_Number__c) Integer 
    from Contact
    where AccountId IN:deactconacctSet and Contact_Status__c ='Active' and (Partner_Admin_Sequence_Number__c !=null and Partner_Admin_Sequence_Number__c!=0)  group by accountid
    ]);
```

Comment: I already had this issue, but I solved doing the aggregate thru a loop.

Comment: Can you try `accountid Id` make I in uppercase?

Comment: Now it is throwing another error:-System.SObjectException: Invalid field accountid for AggregateResult: ()

Comment: @monigangireddy can you also try `AccountId`

Comment: Running a MIN() on IDs? what is the purpose of this? .. just wondering..

Answer (score 4):

If your `deactconacctSet` includes a null then `accountId` (and so its alias `id`used in the Map constructor) could be null. Add an additional `AccountId != null` to avoid that:

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
    select accountid id, min(id), min(Partner_Admin_Sequence_Number__c) Integer 
    from Contact
    where AccountId IN:deactconacctSet
    and AccountId != null
    and Contact_Status__c ='Active'
    and (Partner_Admin_Sequence_Number__c !=null and Partner_Admin_Sequence_Number__c!=0)  
    group by accountid
]);
```